# Avoid AJAX request repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I just saw ajax tooltip that Facebook use to see people who likes some comments.

At first hover the engine made an ajax request, but after that when I hover again the engine doesn't made any ajax request but still show anyone who likes that comments.

Is facebook stored every data on every single request I made into some variable in javascript or what?

Please, I need some clue :D

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: just because a piece of information is not *visible* in an html page doesn't mean it's not there.

Comment: This isn't a forum. This is a place to get help with your code.

Comment: sorry, wrong question then :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if your servers were lucky enough to be hit as much as Facebook, I expect you'd cache on the client as much as possible as well!  It's fairy trivial to maintain a cache in a global variable in Javascript, or to attach data to the DOM.

Something like:

```
var fbCached = {};

//Do AJAX call for post postID...

fbCached.postID = ajaxResponse;
```

I'm not really interested in how Facebook actually avoid repeated AJAX calls - this is just how I'd do it.  They might also store a timestamp of when the AJAX call was made, so they can see if it's worth re-checking posts.

Comment: they cached the data into some variable then?
how much data can be stored in javascript variable?
thanks for your answer :)